org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:Error creating bean Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0
I am new to Spring boot and I have encountered the below error which I am not sure of how to resolve it. I will appreciate your help in resolving the below error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
The offending code is as follows:
package elements.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1ka").password(passwordEncoder.encode("y445uri125")).roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("user2ka").password(passwordEncoder.encode("sa678sha769")).roles("USER");
    }
}


I am using spring Boot V3.3.4
Thank you so much for your help.

you defined PasswordEncoder bean in the same class that needs it to be created. Just move PasswordEncoder bean definition to another Configuration class:
@Configuration
public class FooConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
} 


No need to do that. Just inject the PasswordEncoder into the configureGlobal method and not as a field/constructor. No need to add the complexity of an extra configuration class.

You are making things overly complex, you don't need the configureGlobal method. You can just define a UserDetailsService which will be automatically  picked up. In the method constructing the UserDetailsService you can just inject the PasswordEncoder in use.
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
  var usr1 = User.builder()
        .username("user1ka")
        .password(encoder.encode("y445uri125"))
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
  var usr2 = User.builder()
        .username("user2ka")
        .password(encoder.encode("sa678sha769"))
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
  return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(usr1, usr2);
} 

Now your configuration class is a lot simpler as well.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) { ... }
}


Thank you so much for your proposed resolution. I have tried it and it did work as well. This is much appreciated.
